# Calculation of Correlation Matrix

Tags: correlation, beamforming, array-signal-processing

In the description of any [Beamforming Technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beamforming) for microphone array signal processing there is a usage of the co-relation matrix.

What is the use of calculating such a co-relation matrix in such algorithms?

Comment: This could use a little more own research! So, pick a beamforming technique, and figure out what it does. I don't really see how asking this here reduces your workload.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you calculate it or sometimes you know it by the assumptions of a particular problem. Most typically you estimate it 
$$
R=\frac{1}{N} \sum x_k x_k^H
$$
where $x_k$ is a vector of outputs at time $k$.  This is the “narrow band” case, at a single frequency.  The inverse of  $R$ is often more important.

$R$ is sometimes called the cross spectral density matrix CSDM and sometimes the cross matrix

The theoretical root of importance $R$ is that it represents the covariance of a Gaussian probability density . 
$$ 
w^H R w
$$
Is the expected output power the array given $w$ which is the weight vector,  A large number of algorithms are  based on power and power is related to SNR,

If $R$ is estimated or known , you can calculate the weights of the MVDR beam former.  Which is one application.

Another is that you can spatially whiten the output of sensors with the square root of $R$

The eigenvalues of $R$ are important in subspace techniques like MUSIC .

There are more applications but the common assumption is that your data is Gaussian or similar to Gaussian